# Loading external properties file in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have below spring configuration. I am using spring 3 and windows OS.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>file:/extprops/conf/usercred.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

In above config, am trying to load external properties file `file:/extprops/conf/usercred.properties` and it is working. Here I did not specify the drive location in which the properties file resides. Do i need to specify the drive info in path like `C` or `D` drive ? Do i need to keep App server and properties file in the same drive ?

Comment: If it is working without a drive letter, than you don't have to.

Comment: Since it's working, obviously you don't need to specify drive name. :)

Comment: Do i need to keep App server and properties file in the same drive ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify drive, it uses drive from current work directory which is that you are using during the launch of a process. So, it works, but unreliable - if you run the process e.g. by link from different drive, then it may not work. So, specify the drive too, like this:

```
file:///C:/extprops/conf/usercred.properties
```

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_url

Answer (score 0):

Also, a better/standard approach will be to create an environment variable in the system whose value will contain the path to the propery file.

Then in the configuration file, you can write as :

```
file:${your.prop.folder}/myproperties.properties.
```

This Saves efforts when there's a change in your property file location.

Comment: Bad idea to compose URL in this fashion. Just use environment variable as `your.prop.url` so it is possible to pass any url, not only its fragment.

Comment: could you provide example ?

Answer (score 0):

i think the property file should be there on classpath and that is the correct place for it...beacause that ways it is independent of path so if OS is windows or linux,it wont make any problem.